# Confused about the placement of commas in the following sentences

Tags: commas

"I believe in no God, no invisible man in the sky. But there is something more powerful than each of us, a combination of our efforts, a Great Chain of industry that unites us." - Andrew Ryan

What are the rules that permit the use of commas after the words "God", "us" and "efforts"?

Comment: This sounds like Ayn Rand, but as it turns out it is [from a character named Andrew Ryan](https://bioshock.fandom.com/wiki/The_Great_Chain_(Audio_Diary)), (almost an anagram). You should source your quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all examples of non-restrictive appositive noun phrases, which require the use of commas.

Non-restrictive appositive noun phrases add additional information to further describe/quantify/specify/develop the preceding noun phrase. They are however, non-restrictive (rather than essential or restrictive) because they can be removed without significant change in meaning to the overall sentence. Removing them may lessen the detail or reduce the propositional impact, but the meaning is still clear.

> I believe in no God, no invisible man in the sky [2]. But there is
>   something more powerful than each of us, a combination of our efforts [3],
>   a Great Chain of industry that unites us[4]

In the first sentence [2] can be removed.
In the second sentence [4] can be removed.
In the second sentence, however, it is more difficult to remove [3] without [4], as [4] seems to work in close logical apposition to *efforts*.

Comment: I would disagree that both [3] and [4] are nonessential; removing them also removes the clarification of what the "something" is in the main clause.

Comment: Hello, matt. There _is_ the option of using more heavy-duty separators – the dash and the ellipsis.

Comment: @geekahedron You are confusing the different senses of the word *nonessential*. Here, it doesn't mean *not essential to understanding* but *not essential to the independence of the clause*.

Comment: I'm not sure that I am. "An essential appositive phrase provides information that is necessary for identifying the noun or pronoun that precedes it … In contrast, a nonessential appositive phrase provides additional information about a noun or pronoun in a sentence whose meaning is already clear" ([K12 Reader](https://www.k12reader.com/term/appositive-phrase/)). Without at least one of the two appositive phrases in the second sentence, the meaning of "something" is not clearly identified.

Comment: @geekahedron 'something' is 'identified' by the defining (n.b.) reduced relative clause - 'more powerful than us'.

Comment: What if I said, for example, "there is something more powerful than each of us, the devil himself"? You need the appositive to convey the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: @geekahedron yes, you need the appositive in your sentence to add detail, but the sentence still makes sense (and has meaning) without it. A sentence does not need the added detail of a non-restrictive appositive for it to have meaning.

Comment: @mattxxx4 Without the appositive, it doesn't have the *same* meaning. That's what makes it essential. L

Comment: @geekahedron see previous comments